# How to prevent page reload in Firefox after appending iframe?

Tags: javascript, firefox, iframe

I am dynamically adding an iframe to my page. However, this causes Firefox 78.0.2 to reload the page. It seems this doesn't happen in Chrome.

Here is a fiddle, which demonstrates the issue https://jsfiddle.net/a3ey684f/

```
    $('input').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#youtube").append('<iframe width="200" height="100" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zoMYU_nOGNg?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>');
    })
```

I've checked other threads but I didn't find an answer.
How can the page reload be prevented?

Comment: That fiddle doesn't reload the page. I can even click the button multiple times and the video will appear multiple times, proving that the page doesn't reload (also Firefox 78.0.2)

Comment: One thing that might help is in your developer tools to turn on "Persist Logs" in the network tab and look at the "Cause" column when the reload occurs. That will tell you what is causing the reload (like if it's some JavaScript code).

Comment: How about this - https://jsfiddle.net/ap0u2vfm/3/

Comment: @ChrisG I can clearly see the reload button changing.

Comment: Yes, that's because Firefox is loading the iframe src; it doesn't mean your page is reloading. Afaik this is a relatively recent change; during network activity, the reload button does change into a cancel button. It's just Firefox though.